# Не происходит событие onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку follow, она превращалась в unfollow с другими стилями.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $(this).addClass("clicked btn-2");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-1");
    $(this).html("Unfollow");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("btn-1");
    $(this).removeClass("clicked btn-2");
    $(this).html("Follow");
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-1 {
  border: none;
}

.btn-2 {
  /*display: none;*/
  background-color: greenyellow;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0;
}

.block:hover .btn-1 {
  display: none;
}

.block:hover .btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-pressed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img src="img/1.png" align="top"> John Adams
  <div class="block">
    <button class="btn-1"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
    <button id="btn" class="btn-2">Follow me</button>
  </div>
  <br>102

</div>
```

Comment: И какие стили должны быть у кнопки "Unfollow"?

Comment: она должна стать btn-pressed, переписал js файл так:

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass("clicked") ) {
        $(this).addClass("clicked btn-pressed");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-2");
        $(this).html("Unfollow");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("btn-2");
        $(this).removeClass("clicked btn-pressed");
        $(this).html("Follow");
    }
 });

не спасло(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас в стилях нет класса `.clicked`, но есть `.btn-pressed`, соответственно, на его наличие и нужно проверять.

Во-вторых, при отжатии кнопки вы удаляете класс `.btn-2`, которые делает вашу кнопку скрытой, а этого, насколько понимаю, вам не надо.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("btn-pressed")) {
    $(this).addClass("btn-pressed").html("Unfollow");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("btn-pressed").html("Follow");
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-1 {
  border: none;
}

.btn-2 {
  display: none;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0;
}

.block:hover .btn-1 {
  display: none;
}

.block:hover .btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-pressed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>John Adams
  <div class="block">
    <button class="btn-1"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle">+</i></button>
    <button id="btn" class="btn-2">Follow me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можете ещё раз глянуть на http://www.lesha.wemakesites.ru/
всё сделал как у вас, все равно не работает...

Comment: @lesha_ber оберните код внутри js.js в `$(document).ready(function() {тут ваш код});`